# Cannot receive data in Django View from frontend through Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, post

I am trying to post data from frontend to Django view, and render the view inside another page, but I don't receive any data from frontend. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Jquery:

```
 <script>
            window.getDisplayConfirmation = function(ele){
                   var row = $(ele).closest('tr');
                   var displayObjectId1 = row.find('td').eq(2).text()
                   console.log(typeof(displayObjectId1))
                   console.log(displayObjectId1)
                   var displayObjectId = parseInt(displayObjectId1)
                   $.ajax({

                     url:'/detailedData/',
                     data: {
                       'displayObjectId': displayObjectId
                            },

                    success: function(){
                        alert('Vote successful!');
                        $("#dataDisplayArea").load("/detailedData/");
                        },
                        });
                    };

        </script>
```

View:

```
def detailedData(request):
    displayObjectId = request.GET.get('displayObjectId')
    displayObjects = TemporaryModel.objects.get(id=displayObjectId)
    return render(request, 'frontend/detailedData.html', {'obj': displayObjects,"receivedObjectId":displayObjectId})
```

html:
this is part of my table in this html page

```
       <td ><button id = "showButton" class ="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="getDisplayConfirmation(this)"> S </button></td>
      <td ><button id = "deleteButton" class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="getDeleteConfirmation(this)"> D</button></td>
      <td >{{ obj.id}}</td>
```

I also have this part on the same html page to include rendered page as a sub-page:

```
  <div id ="dataDisplayArea">
        {% include 'frontend/detailedData.html' %}
    </div>
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
    path('panelOne/', views.panelOne, name='panelOne'),
    path('panelTwo/', views.panelTwo, name='panelTwo'),
    path('detailedData/', views.detailedData, name='detailedData'),
    path('panelThree/', PanelThreeView.as_view(), name='panelThree'),

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is returning data. But your Ajax success function ignores that data, then sends *another* request to the same URL without the parameters. Don't do that. Use the data that is returned.

```
success: function(data){
    alert('Vote successful!');
    $("#dataDisplayArea").html(data);
},
```

Comment: Dear Daniel, thank you so much for your help! This solved my problem, saved me a lot of time!